# what is the OPERATION name in gcloud ai-platform operations wait OPERATION?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-composer, gcp-ai-platform-training

I need to wait for an ML training job to be finished before proceeding with the rest of my workflow.

I am using Composer/Airflow to orchestrate my tasks. 
My first task is launching ML training on AI-platform, then I need to wait for this training to be finished before moving on to the next task.

I am having trouble undertanding the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/operations/wait) which explains how one can wait for an ML operation to be over.

Documentation states:
`gcloud ai-platform operations wait OPERATION`

Currently, my code is:

```
   gcloud ai-platform operations wait {{ params.JOB_NAME }}
```

and I get the error:

```
Running command: gcloud ai-platform operations wait ai_composer_20191119_201848
[2019-11-19 20:18:48,648] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-11-19 20:18:48,647] {bash_operator.py:97} INFO - Output:
[2019-11-19 20:18:49,811] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-11-19 20:18:49,810] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.operations.wait) NOT_FOUND: Field: name Error: The specified job was not found.
[2019-11-19 20:18:49,812] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-11-19 20:18:49,812] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
[2019-11-19 20:18:49,812] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-11-19 20:18:49,812] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - fieldViolations:
[2019-11-19 20:18:49,812] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-11-19 20:18:49,812] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - - description: The specified job was not found.
[2019-11-19 20:18:49,813] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-11-19 20:18:49,812] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - field: name
[2019-11-19 20:18:49,853] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2019-11-19 20:18:49,852] {bash_operator.py:105} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2019-11-19 20:18:49,883] {models.py:1595} ERROR - Bash command failed
```

What is the field OPERATION supposed to have?

For more context, my dag looks like this:

```
with dag:
    env = {}
    env['BUCKET'] = models.Variable.get('bucket_name')
    env['JOB_NAME'] = "ai_composer_{}".format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))
    env['JOB_DIR'] = "gs://{bucket}/jobs/{job_name}".format(bucket=env['BUCKET'], job_name=env['JOB_NAME'])
    env['REGION'] = models.Variable.get('ai_region')
    env['PACKAGE_PATH'] = models.Variable.get('ai_training_package')
    env['CONFIG'] = models.Variable.get('train_config_path', deserialize_json=True)
    env['OUTPUT_FOLDER'] = "{job_dir}/model/".format(job_dir=env['JOB_DIR'])
    env['DUMMY_TRAINING_FILE'] = models.Variable.get('dummy_training_file')


    test_training = BashOperator(
        task_id='test_training',
        xcom_push=True,
        bash_command='gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training {{ params.JOB_NAME }} \
                --region {{ params.REGION }} \
                --scale-tier=CUSTOM \
                --python-version 3.5 \
                --runtime-version 1.13 \
                --master-machine-type n1-highcpu-16 \
                --staging-bucket gs://{{ params.BUCKET }} \
                --job-dir {{ params.JOB_DIR }} \
                --module-name trainer.task \
                --packages {{ params.PACKAGE_PATH }} \
                -- \
                --gcs-bucket gs://{{ params.BUCKET }} \
                --train-file {{ params.DUMMY_TRAINING_FILE }}\
                --verbose-logging \
                --data-type web_views \
                --delimiter , \
                && echo "{{ params.JOB_NAME }}"',
        params=env
    )

    get_ml_status = BashOperator(
        task_id='get_ml_status',
        xcom_push=True,
        bash_command='gcloud ai-platform operations wait {{ params.JOB_NAME }}',
        params=env
    )

test_training >> get_ml_status
```

Here test_training is successful, so a training job is launched before get_ml_status task starts.

Comment: You can call GetJob to check job state.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding a workaround by checking the job status with jobs describe.

```
output = sh.gcloud("ai-platform", "jobs", "describe", job_name)
```

I do a while loop until the state is `SUCCEEDED` or `FAILED`.